# `scanFloat` was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift

method `scanFloat` was deprecated in iOS 13.0,

> `func scanFloat(_ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?) -> Bool`

> Scans for a float value, returning a found value by reference.

I can use `for loop` to solve it.

any other advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner).

There is an improved [replacement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/3200284-scanfloat)

```
func scanFloat(representation: Scanner.NumberRepresentation = .decimal) -> Float?
```

Comment: Interestingly, the docs do not say that the previous `scanFloat` is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/1411677-scanfloat